# i'm unable to install gem debugger on rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, ruby-on-rails-4

ruby version is 2.1.0 and rails version is 4.1.1

my gem file got like below
gem 'debugger'

when i run command bundle install, i get error like below:
@@
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.6.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'` succeeds before bundling.
@@

seeking suggestion to solve the issue.

Comment: What do you see when you run `gem install debugger -v '1.6.8'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`debugger` isn't compatible with Ruby 2 and above, it's a known issue.

https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/125#issuecomment-43353446

The author recommends using [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) or [debugger2](https://github.com/ko1/debugger2) instead.

Comment: I had this problem on my ubuntu production environment. As I don't need debugger on production, I simply removed debugger from my gemfile.

Answer (score 2):

This Worked for me:

Please replace

> gem 'pry-debugger'

with

> gem 'pry-byebug'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Debugger is not fully supported for Ruby 2.x.x.

Issue#118 is popular issue which addresses the same. Though it mentions that debugger 1.6.6 must be supported by Ruby 2.1.1, the users are still encountering the similar errors as you are.

Also, this is especially mentioned in their known issues.

You can try to follow that discussion to troubleshoot your problem.
Additionally, this may help:

```
rm Gemfile.lock
gem install debugger-ruby_core_source
gem update
bundle install
```

The other solution in issue discusses the possibility of updating Ruby binary.

If nothing works, and if you can possibly change the ruby/rails versions, I can suggest my current combination:

```
ruby 2.0.0-p195
rails 4.0.0
```

They work perfectly fine with debugger gem.

Answer (score 0):

debugger gem doesn't work with Ruby 2.1+. Instead try byebug.